# You cannot run a notebook job on a cluster running Databricks Basic

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, cluster-computing, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

```
Error code
3201
Troubleshooting guide
Failure type
User configuration issue
Details
You cannot run a notebook job on a cluster running Databricks Basic.
Source
```

I am gettig this error when i try to run my Databrick notebook in ADF. I am not understanding what this means. I tried to create a different type of cluster, but still failing due to this error.

Can Azure guru please help me with this.

Comment: Are you able to run the notebook from Databricks workspace?

Comment: @PratikSomaiya yes, I am able to run the script from azure Databrick workspace. No issue  at all. Now I am getting a different error this time. It is saying I am exceeding the core limit for my region. I am living in New Zealand and my closest data center is Australia East. But it is still running well from Azure Databrick workstation, but from Azure Data Factory. The error messages are confusing me as I am not even running a big chunk of script.

Comment: ok got it, I haven't seen such an error as all Databricks notebook activity that I used were successful, can you try upgrading to a Standard tier once?

Comment: Azure subscriptions have a CPU core quota limit which restricts the number of CPU cores you can use. This is a hard limit. See these articles from `Microsoft` for details - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/kb/clusters/calculate-number-of-cores, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/kb/clusters/azure-core-limit

Comment: @DKNY aha, that is probably why then. I am on a free trial subscription, and Microsoft is probably limiting the number of CPU cores I can use with my subscription. I probably need to upgrade my subscription. Does that mean I have to be on a pay as you go subscription though?

Comment: @user86907 Yep, you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am on a free trial subscription, and Microsoft is probably limiting the number of CPU cores I can use with my current subscription. I need to upgrade my subscription.

Answer (score 1):

You can post your comment as answer and accept it. I have mentioned below how you can upgrade your subscription and resolve this issue.

To upgrade you need to select `Standard` or `Premium` Pricing Tier while creating resource.

[image]